# Windows 10 DNS issue, switching between default and custom DNS server

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, google-dns

I am having problems with my internet. The problem switches between I cannot access the internet using the default DNS settings (which I solve by setting my DNS server to Google (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)), and these settings not working and needing to switch back to the default DNS settings.

This is happening everyday. I am on Windows 10 (OS build 14393.447).

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Windows Key -> regedit Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces  -> search for your dns entry -> NameServer 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 Export this value for example to your desktop. Now you can change your dns Server with this regist file .

Comment: When the problem occurs, does `ipconfig /flushdns` from the command line fix it?  If so, then you have some caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled IPv6 and the issue went away.